# ORACLE(TOAD) CASE with multiple conditions for different updates

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to update qualifications in a Oracle DB, I am running into a problem where my script errors.
I would usually create a few smaller update statements to get the job done.

However I thought it would be better to do one query, this is simple but my background is mostly on T-SQL and mySQL not Oracle.

So help would be appreciated.
My Statement.

```
--ALTER SESSION TO CHANGE DT--
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

--Update
Update Qualifications_t
Set (COMMENTS = 'Task'),
    (Expiry_DTS = CASE Expiry_DTS
    When cd = '1'
    Then Expiry_DTS = '31/12/2016 23:59:00'
    When cd = '2'
    Then Expiry_DTS = '01/07/2019 23:59:00'
    When cd = '3'
    Then Expiry_DTS = '31/12/1999 23:59:00'
    When cd = '4'
    Then Expiry_DTS = '31/08/2021 23:59:00'
    When cd = '5'
    Then Expiry_DTS = '17/06/2021 23:59:00')
END
Where EXPIRY_DTS IS NULL;

--SELECT
Select * 
from QUALIFICATIONS_T
where COMMENTS = 'Task';
```

Error at line 5
ORA-00905: missing keyword
Yes, I googled it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the update assignments.

Then: it's not clear what you mean by the `case` expression. Perhaps this:

```
update qualifications_t
set    comments   = 'task',
       expiry_dts = case when cd = '1' then to_date('31/12/2016 23:59:00',
                                                    'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                         when cd = '2' then to_date(....)
                                  (etc.)
                    end
where  expiry_dts is null
;
```

Notice the structure of a `case` expression. The name of the column you are updating doesn't belong after the keyword `case`, and the `case` expression "returns" values directly, not through assignments. There should be only one assignment ("equal sign"); the `case` expression is evaluated and returns a single value, used for update.

Note also the proper way to represent `date` values (assuming the column data type is `date`, as it should be; if it isn't, you should fix that first).